# Archlinux + MATE Terminal - `.bash_profile` is not being sourced

Tags: terminal, archlinux, bash, mate

I am using Arch Linux with MATE as desktop environment. So terminal emulator is MATE Terminal. Recently I installed [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) with `gem install jekyll`. But when I ran `jekyll -v` it says `bash: jekyll: command not found`. So I tried to add path of Jekyll to PATH variable.

I ran `PATH=$PATH/$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin` and it worked perfectly. Now I can run jekyll commands. To add it permanently to PATH variable I edited the `~/.bash_profile` file like following. It is not working after reboot. But 
`source ~/.bash_profile` works perfectly.

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

export PATH="${PATH}:/home/heisenberg/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin"
```

According to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables#Per_user) this is the proper way to concat something permanantly to PATH. But it isn't working. Can somebody figure me out where the wrong is?

[N. B. : Adding the same line in `~/.bashrc` is doing okay.]

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$PATH==="`?

Comment: @chepner, `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl===`

Comment: How are you logging in/running bash when this doesn't work?

Comment: `source ~/.bash_profile` is working fine but after rebooting it is gone. :(

Comment: It sounds like `bash` isn't your login shell, so that `.bash_profile` isn't being sourced at all.

Comment: It worked now. I put the same line in `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile` and it worked, But why is that?

Comment: @chepner, `echo $SHELL` output is `/bin/bash`

Comment: @taufique, the difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` is that the former is run for a *login* shell, whereas the latter is run for an interactive shell that is *not* a login shell. This is described in the "INVOCATION" section of the bash man page. Is it possible that your login shell is something other than bash, and that you launch bash after login?

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question (well documented as it is). Please use `flag` link at the bottom of your Q to as a moderator to move to http://unix.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the option it is given, `bash` can be run as an *interactive shell* or *login shell*. The default *interactive shell* mode does not read `~/.bash_profile`. *login shell* bash do.

See:

First, some setup:

```
% cat ~/.bashrc
…
export BASHRC="yes"
…
% cat ~/.bash_profile
…
export BASH_PROFILE="yes"
…
```

Now run a regular (*interactive*) bash:

```
% bash
[galaux@magenta ~]$ echo $BASHRC
yes
[galaux@magenta ~]$ echo $BASH_PROFILE
```

Notice we did **not** get `yes` with this last one.

Now with a *login* shell:

```
% bash --login
[galaux@magenta ~]$ echo $BASHRC
yes
[galaux@magenta ~]$ echo $BASH_PROFILE
yes
```

See paragraph *INVOCATION* from `man bash`.